# Album deezer not appear

Tags: deezer

I have a problem with a query that does not react the same way in a browser or in my php file.

> [Http://api.deezer.com/search/album?q=BRETONNE+Nolwenn%2BLeroy](http://api.deezer.com/search/album?q=BRETONNE%20Nolwenn%2BLeroy)

In my browser, the json file is correct.
If I do `print_r` in my php file
I receive:

```
{"data": [], "total": 0}
```

For more information, most of my other albums are found.

---

That is what i'm actually using :

```
// On teste quand  même avec le titre si cela ne donne rien avec l'id
                if ($resultat_json_d->error)
                {

                    $album_title=strtoupper($album_title);
                    $url_deezer = 'http://api.deezer.com/search/album?q='.urlencode($album_title." ".$nom_aut);
                    //$url_deezer = 'https://api.deezer.com/search?q=album:"'.urlencode($album_title).'" artist: "'.urlencode($auteur).'"';
                    //$url_deezer = 'https://api.deezer.com/search?q=album:bretonne';
                    $datadeezer =array('index'=>'0','limit'=>'1','output'=>'json');
                    $options_d = array(
                            'http' => array(
                                    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                                    'method'  => 'GET',
                                    'content' => "&".http_build_query($datadeezer)
                            )
                    );
                    $context_d  = stream_context_create($options_d);
                    $resultat_brut_deezer = file_get_contents($url_deezer,false,$context_d);
                    $resultat_json_d=json_decode($resultat_brut_deezer);
                    echo $url_deezer.'<br>';                        
                }

                if ($resultat_brut_deezer<>'{"data":[],"total":0}' && $resultat_brut_deezer<>'{"error":{"type":"DataException","message":"no data","code":800}}') 
                {

                    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) 
                    {
                        $album_id = $resultat_json_d->data[$i]->id;
                        $album_title_d = $resultat_json_d->data[$i]->title;
                        $artiste=$resultat_json_d->data[$i]->artist->name;

                        if(stristr($artiste,$nom_aut) || stristr($artiste,$prenom_aut))
                        {
                            $trouve2=true;
                            break;
                        }   
                        IF (stristr($artiste,$premiermot))
                        {
                            $trouve2=true;
                            break;
                        }
                        /* if ($album_title_d==$album_title)
                        {
                            $trouve2=true;
                            break;
                        } */

                    }
                }   

                }

                if ($trouve2 == true)
                {
                        //echo $album_id;
                        echo '<script>
                                    (function(d, s, id) {
                                        var js, djs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                                        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                                        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                                        js.src = "https://e-cdns-files.dzcdn.net/js/widget/loader.js";
                                        djs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, djs);
                                    }(document, "script", "deezer-widget-loader"));
                                </script>'  ;
                        echo '<div class="deezer-widget-player" data-src= "https://www.deezer.com/plugins/player?format=classic&autoplay=false&playlist=true&width=700&height=350&color=007FEB&layout=dark&size=medium&type=album&id='.$album_id.'&app_id=1" data-scrolling="no" data-frameborder="0" data-allowTransparency="true" data-width="700" data-height="350"></div>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<div><p>Album non trouvé sur Deezer.</p></div>';
                    //echo '1';
                }
```

Comment: It is normal as the catalog depends on the country where you are located. Your server must be located in a country where this album is not available, instead of your current location.

Comment: Thanks fred for your reply. Do you know if it is possible to remedy this? My site is hosted by amen in Italy